# Linq to Entity Left Outer Join

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, left-join

I have an Entity model with Invoices, AffiliateCommissions and AffiliateCommissionPayments.

Invoice to AffiliateCommission is a one to many, AffiliateCommission to AffiliateCommissionPayment is also a one to many

I am trying to make a query that will return All Invoices that HAVE a commission but not necessarily have a related commissionPayment. I want to show the invoices with commissions whether they have a commission payment or not.

Query looks something like:

```
using (var context = new MyEntitities())
{
   var invoices = from i in context.Invoices
   from ac in i.AffiliateCommissions
   join acp in context.AffiliateCommissionPayments on ac.affiliateCommissionID equals acp.AffiliateCommission.affiliateCommissionID 
   where ac.Affiliate.affiliateID == affiliateID
   select new
   {
      companyName = i.User.companyName,
      userName = i.User.fullName,
      email = i.User.emailAddress, 
      invoiceEndDate = i.invoicedUntilDate,
      invoiceNumber = i.invoiceNumber,
      invoiceAmount = i.netAmount,
      commissionAmount = ac.amount,
      datePaid = acp.paymentDate,
      checkNumber = acp.checkNumber
   };
   return invoices.ToList();
}
```

This query above only returns items with an AffiliateCommissionPayment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if EF supports this (nor am I sure if you are using EF2 or EF4), but this is the solution in Linq2Sql so it might be worth trying:

```
using (var context = new MyEntitities()) 
{ 
   var invoices = from i in context.Invoices 
   from ac in i.AffiliateCommissions 
   join acp in context.AffiliateCommissionPayments on ac.affiliateCommissionID equals acp.AffiliateCommission.affiliateCommissionID into acp_join
   from acp_join_default in acpg.DefaultIfEmpty()
   where ac.Affiliate.affiliateID == affiliateID 
   select new 
   { 
      companyName = i.User.companyName, 
      userName = i.User.fullName, 
      email = i.User.emailAddress,  
      invoiceEndDate = i.invoicedUntilDate, 
      invoiceNumber = i.invoiceNumber, 
      invoiceAmount = i.netAmount, 
      commissionAmount = ac.amount, 
      datePaid = acp.paymentDate, 
      checkNumber = acp.checkNumber 
   }; 
   return invoices.ToList(); 
}
```

The main change here is the `into acpg` after your `join`, and the `DefaultIfEmpty` line.

Comment: Thanks, I am using EF2 and DefaultIfEmpty is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

[It's almost always a mistake to use `join` in LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entities](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/).

Guessing that the association from `AffiliateCommission` to `AffiliateCommissionPayment` is called `Payment`, you can just do:

```
using (var context = new MyEntitities())
{
   var invoices = from i in context.Invoices
   from ac in i.AffiliateCommissions
   where ac.Affiliate.affiliateID == affiliateID
   select new
   {
      companyName = i.User.companyName,
      userName = i.User.fullName,
      email = i.User.emailAddress, 
      invoiceEndDate = i.invoicedUntilDate,
      invoiceNumber = i.invoiceNumber,
      invoiceAmount = i.netAmount,
      commissionAmount = ac.amount,
      datePaid = (DateTime?) ac.Payment.paymentDate,
      checkNumber = (int?) ac.Payment.checkNumber
   };
   return invoices.ToList();
}
```

LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entities will both coalesce nulls. The casts are necessary because the inferred type will be based on the type of `AffiliateCommissionPayment.paymentDate`, which might not be nullable. If it is, you don't need the cast.